# How to change row background color of according to value in collectionView in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to change color of background row in collectionView according to date.

For example:

```
foreach(var item in myList) 
{
    if (item.ExpiryDate <= DateTime.Now )
    {
        Mylistrow.BackgroundColor = Color.Coral
    }
    else if (item.ExpiryDate > DateTime.Now.AddMonth(3))
    {
        Mylistrow.BackgroundColor = Color.Orange
    }
}
```

Comment: bind the `BackgroundColor` property to the `ExpiryDate` property, and use an `IValueConverter` to convert it to a color

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it

Comment: there are numerous existing questions as well as official documentation on using `IValueConverter`.  Please take the time to do some research, and if you are still having problems, show us what you've tried and the specific problem or error you're having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason suggested, you can [Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to convert type to `Color` according to date.

I create a demo which works well, you can refer to it:

1. Create a IValueConverter: DateColorConverter.cs：

```
    public class DateColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((DateTime)value).Date <= DateTime.Now.Date) return Color.Coral;

            else if ( ((DateTime)value).Date > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3) ) return Color.Orange;

            return Color.Default;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

2. **XAML**:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:DateColorConverter x:Key="DateColor" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyItem">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding ExpiryDate,Converter={StaticResource DateColor}}">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ExpiryDate}"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

**Code-behind**:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; set; }
public MainPage()
{
      InitializeComponent();

      Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>() {       
      new MyItem{ExpiryDate=DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4)},
      new MyItem{ExpiryDate=DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4)},
      new MyItem{ExpiryDate=DateTime.Now},
      new MyItem{ExpiryDate=DateTime.Now},
};

     BindingContext = this;
}
```

3. The Mode class: `MyItem.cs`

```
public class MyItem
{
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```